# Java read HMAC-SHA1 signed messages

Tags: java, network-programming, hmacsha1

We have some network controllers(Aruba) that can send  HMAC-SHA1 signed messages to RTLS server on UDP port. We have written and simple Java program and deployed on a Linux server that receives the data packets on the UDP ports. The controllers use a key to sign the messages and hence we are getting the messages in the digested format as below. Is there a way we can extract the actual messages from this using the shared key ?

RECEIVED: *gdrÈ$ï¿½pï¿½ï¿½sï¿½~ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½qï¿½ï¿½ï¿½2
RECEIVED: ,$drÈï¿½H)ï¿½ï¿½5ï¿½rï¿½[ï¿½b×Cï¿½` ï¿½ï¿½
RECEIVED: 0ï¿½
              ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½aï¿½ï¿½#ï¿½Aï¿½cLï¿½i ï¿½?ï¿½ï¿½
RECEIVED: +ï¿½drï¿½ï¿½#J~e%ï¿½ï¿½Sï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½ï¿½??

Java code that receives the message:

```
   public class UDPServer
{
   public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
      {
         DatagramSocket serverSocket = new DatagramSocket(9999);
            byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];
            byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];
            while(true)
               {
                  DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);
                  serverSocket.receive(receivePacket);
                  String response = new String(receivePacket.getData(), 0, 
                          receivePacket.getLength(), "UTF-8");

                  System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + response);
//                
               }
      }
}
```

Comment: Might be missing your question, but HMACs are used to ensure the message is authentic. The shared key and the message are used to produce a special hash and if it equals to the hash sent at the end of a message, then the message is authentic. So if just an HMAC is used, then the rest of the data is in plain text and should be able to be read (could be in a binary format, check documentation). However if encryption is being used also, then you have to use the shared key to decrypt the data first in order to read it.

Answer (score 0):

We found the message was serialized using google protubuf. Using the .proto file we were able to generate the required object and deserialize.